# get a value from an object property and assign it to a C # string value

Tags: c#, .net

I have a below code to capture an objects values:

```
var key = fulfillment.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("operator")).GetValue(fulfillment);
```

the code return:

[image]

the Operator property type is:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "operator")] 
public object Operator { get; set; }
```

i want to get the name value of the index 1 -> `OMS_OPERATOR_AUTOMATED` and assign it to another string variable. How can i do this  ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) The first image's content should be pasted as text instead. The second image likely is a reasonable use of a screenshot but unfortunately, it's too small. Please [edit] the question and fix those issues.

Comment: @41686d6564 ok done

Comment: Looks like your object is a collection of key value pairs. So you will not need to use reflection. `var key = ...key.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ToLower().Contains("operator"))?.Value;`

Comment: @SebastianSiemens the property `Value` doesnt exists, just `GetValue()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final answer after looking at code and data structure the answer was:

```cs
var foundOperator = (Dictionary<string, object>) fulfillment.Operator;
var teste = foundOperator["name"];
```

Comment: im not using the property accessor because is not possible - > `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expressionof type 'object'`

Comment: What is the type of "Operator"?

Comment: [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "operator")]
        public object Operator { get; set; }

Comment: @Desalex please read my re-submission

Comment: ty for your answer but i cant change the Operator type because 
this is used elsewhere in the system. This need to remain an object type

Comment: I see, well you could just cast the Operator to the correct type before trying to use the indexing, see my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224876/discussion-between-simon-curtis-and-desalex).

Comment: FilePath ? i didnt understand, Why filepath ? Im not work with files.